# Not able to connect to multiple IBM MQ channels with multiple SSL certs using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, tls1.2

Not able to connect to multiple `IBM MQ` channels with multiple `SSL` certs and `Spring Boot`

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
    <artifactId>sslcontext-kickstart</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** Using sslcontext-kickstart api and more documentation can be found here

https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart

**MulticertApplication.java**

```
public class MulticertApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private SSLContextService sslContextService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MulticertApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws JMSException {
        // Both WORKS !!
        testConnectionWithIndividualSSL("APP1");
        log.info("APP1 CONNECTION SUCCESS WITH INDIVIDUAL SSL !!");
        testConnectionWithIndividualSSL("APP2");
        log.info("APP2 CONNECTION SUCCESS WITH INDIVIDUAL SSL !!");

        // Does NOT WORK !!
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContextService.getCombinedSSLSocketFactory();
        testConnectionWithCombinedSSL(sslSocketFactory, "APP1");
        log.info("APP1 CONNECTION SUCCESS WITH COMBINED SSL !!");
        testConnectionWithCombinedSSL(sslSocketFactory, "APP2");
        log.info("APP2 CONNECTION SUCCESS WITH COMBINED SSL !!");
    }

    private void testConnectionWithIndividualSSL(String app) throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName("MQHOST.company.net");
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(1414);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("MQHOST");
        if (app.equalsIgnoreCase("APP1")) {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("APP1.SVRCONN.TLS");
        } else {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("APP2.SVRCONN.TLS");
        }
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLFipsRequired(false);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContextService.getSSLSocketFactory(app));
        MQQueueConnection mqQueueConnection = (MQQueueConnection) mqQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        mqQueueConnection.start();
        mqQueueConnection.stop();
        mqQueueConnection.close();
    }

    private void testConnectionWithCombinedSSL(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, String app) throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName("MQHOST.company.net");
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(1414);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("MQHOST");
        if (app.equalsIgnoreCase("APP1")) {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("APP1.SVRCONN.TLS");
        } else {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel("APP2.SVRCONN.TLS");
        }
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLFipsRequired(false);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        MQQueueConnection mqQueueConnection = (MQQueueConnection) mqQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        mqQueueConnection.start();
        mqQueueConnection.stop();
        mqQueueConnection.close();
    }

}
```

**SSLContextService.java**

```
@Service 
public class SSLContextService {

    private static final String APP1_JKS_PWD = "abc";
    private static final String APP2_JKS_PWD = "def";

    public SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(String app) {
        log.info("app: " + app);
        if (app.equalsIgnoreCase("APP1")) {
            return SSLFactory.builder()
                    .withIdentityMaterial("app1.jks", APP1_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                    .withTrustMaterial("app1.jks", APP1_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                    .build().getSslContext().getSocketFactory();
        } else if (app.equalsIgnoreCase("APP2")) {
            return SSLFactory.builder()
                    .withIdentityMaterial("app2.jks", APP2_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                    .withTrustMaterial("app2.jks", APP2_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                    .build().getSslContext().getSocketFactory();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public SSLSocketFactory getCombinedSSLSocketFactory() {
        return SSLFactory.builder()
                .withIdentityMaterial("app1.jks", APP1_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                .withIdentityMaterial("app2.jks", APP2_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                .withTrustMaterial("app1.jks", APP1_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                .withTrustMaterial("app2.jks", APP2_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
                .build().getSslContext().getSocketFactory();
    }

}
```

**Error Log:**

```
2021-09-30 17:55:51.892  INFO 62988 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.multicert.MulticertApplication      : Started MulticertApplication in 3.414 seconds (JVM running for 4.448)
2021-09-30 17:55:51.899  INFO 62988 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.multicert.service.SSLContextService  : app: APP1
2021-09-30 17:55:52.513  INFO 62988 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.multicert.MulticertApplication      : APP1 CONNECTION SUCCESS WITH INDIVIDUAL SSL !!
2021-09-30 17:55:52.514  INFO 62988 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.multicert.service.SSLContextService  : app: APP2
2021-09-30 17:55:52.555  INFO 62988 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.multicert.MulticertApplication      : APP2 CONNECTION SUCCESS WITH INDIVIDUAL SSL !!
2021-09-30 17:55:52.597  INFO 62988 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.multicert.MulticertApplication      : APP1 CONNECTION SUCCESS WITH COMBINED SSL !!
2021-09-30 17:55:52.641  INFO 62988 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-30 17:55:52.663 ERROR 62988 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.example.multicert.MulticertApplication.main(MulticertApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'MQHOST' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'MQHOST.company.net(1414)'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:424) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    at com.example.multicert.MulticertApplication.testConnectionWithCombinedSSL(MulticertApplication.java:76) [classes/:na]
    at com.example.multicert.MulticertApplication.run(MulticertApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.0.jar:9.1.0.0 - p910-L180705]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are all of the certs in the key store signed by the same issue or different issuers?

Comment: Yes, same issuer. And the first case works. That's what puzzling me :)

Comment: Are you using more than one keystore?

Comment: If all certs are in the same key store it is undetermined which will be used by java.   It picks based on certs that it knows are trusted by the remote server but if all are issued by the same CA then multiple are trusted.   I've seen the first in the key store picked under these circumstances. You would likely need to use multiple key stores to be able to use other certs.  If it is a multi threaded process you would have issues since the java system property that points to the key store is global.   I suggest you use a single cert or split things up so each process has only one cert.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the underlying KeyManager has trouble sending the correct client certificate to ibm mq server. This will occur when using multiple keystores which have the same key algorithm. In that case it will just grab the first client certificate.

So I would suggest to use the additional option for the SSLFactory to correctly route the client certificate to the right ibm mq server. So the following setup should do the trick:

```java
public SSLSocketFactory getCombinedSSLSocketFactory() {
    return SSLFactory.builder()
            .withIdentityMaterial("app1.jks", APP1_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
            .withIdentityMaterial("app2.jks", APP2_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
            .withTrustMaterial("app1.jks", APP1_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
            .withTrustMaterial("app2.jks", APP2_JKS_PWD.toCharArray())
            .withClientIdentityRoute("client-alias-one", "https://[MQHOST-ONE.company.net]:1414/")
            .withClientIdentityRoute("client-alias-two", "https://[MQHOST-TWO.company.net]:8463/")
            .build().getSslContext().getSocketFactory();
}
```

I have never tried this with ibm mq, so I am not sure if this will work. So it is just an assumption. With traditional setup (basic client and server communication) while using multiple keystores it will work. So I am curious if this solution will work for you.

For the `withClientIdentityRoute` you need to pass the alias name of the certificate which is used within the keystore file as the first parameter. The second parameter should be the url of your ibm mq server.

Feel free to read here more in detail: [Routing identity material to specific host](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart#routing-identity-material-to-specific-host)

Can you give it a try and share your results here?

Comment: Ok, how can I find the alias name of the certificate? When I open the .jks file its all gibberish

Comment: Yes you can find it in the jks file and use that. You can also rename it in the jks if that makes it easier

Comment: I mean, when I open the file in Notepad++ it's all unreadable. Do you suggest or recommend any other way or command to figure out the alias ?

Comment: Ah now i understand, you can use KeyStore explorer to view the content of the KeyStore file, you can get the tool from here https://keystore-explorer.org/

Comment: My org doesn't allow any downloads on machine. Let me find another way to figure out the alias

Comment: You can also try the following command `keytool -v -list -keystore app1.jks` the keytool command should be available on your command line interface

Comment: Thanks Hakan, found alias using the above command that you provided and added alias and url both `.withClientIdentityRoute()` but it's not even able to connect to the first one now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237857/discussion-between-hakan54-and-nital).

Comment: Sure Hakan, will ping you sometime tomorrow EST time